# How can I do update with using same id but different content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Currently, I working on form that got an input for image file. After browse image then upload it I will get the id for the image. Here is my code for POST.

```
$("#smallpicture_id").change(function () {
    displayAndShowImage(this,'#smallimg','#smallimg'); 
});

$("#largepicture_id").change(function () {
    displayAndShowImage(this,'#largeimg','#largeimg');
});

function displayAndShowImage(input,targetHtmlElementName) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var files = input.files;
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(targetHtmlElementName).attr('src', 'images/uploading.gif');
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('userfile',files[0],files[0].name);
            createImage(
                config,
                formData,
                {
                    onSuccess : function(data) {
                        $(targetHtmlElementName).attr('src', e.target.result);
                        $.cookie(input.id, data);
                        console.log("Image has been save - Received ID: " + data + " saved in the cookie " + input.id);
                    },
                    onError : function(jqXHR, status) {
                        $(targetHtmlElementName).attr('src', 'images/img-error.png');
                        console.log("ERROR " + jqXHR.responseText + "\r\nstatus = " + status);
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
}
```

Ajax

```
function createImage(cfg,formData,callbacks) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', cfg.url + "/image/", true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // File(s) uploaded.
            callbacks.onSuccess(xhr.responseText.trim());
        } else {
            callbacks.onError(xhr);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

My question is how can I update / delete for my image with using the same id that given to the image. I already can do POST and GET but I still don't get any idea how to update and delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can append two string in `FormData` query identifier and ID (only in case of update & delete), like

```
formData.append('queryType', 'DELETE')
formData.append('imageID', input.id)
```

On server side code (where you have added code for saving new Image) you have to add condintion like this

```
<?php
$identifier=$_POST['queryType'];
if($identifier=="NEW") {
    //save file with new ID and return ID
} elseif ($identifier=="UPDATE")
    //update Image Data ($_FILE) with ID appended in formdata
} elseif ($identifier=="DELETE")
    //Delete existing image at ID specified
}
?>
```

hope this may help.

Comment: thanks, I will try it later and inform you if I got any problem.

Comment: @M.AmirQ from other answer it seems that you are needing client side script to update image there in browser only (and you are having server side code inplace for maintaining Database). can you clarify me once

Answer (score 0):

You can give your elements specific classname for each upload process, which have same id, then run displayAndShowImage function for only elements has "update-this" classname.

```
$("#smallpicture_id").change(function () {

    $(this).addClass("update-this"); // add update-this class
    $(".update-this").not($(this)).removeClass("update-this"); // remove all update-this classnames from all other ones

    // then run your function for only element which has update-this classname
    displayAndShowImage(this,'.update-this'); 
});
```

Comment: thanks, I will try it later and inform you if I got any problem.

Comment: Is it possible I want to delete the old picture with their id and replace with new 1?